# How do I add item to Pidgin menu

Tags: c, gtk, pidgin

I want to add arbitrary item to Pidgin menu. Let it be *Buddies → Show → Groups*. I want it to be checkbutton (like *Buddies → Show → Empty Groups*) with custom function associated. How can I do this?

- [In Pidgin 2.10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23379171/2572082)
- [In Pidgin 3.0.0 (development branch)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382393/2572082)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following example is for Pidgin version 2.10.9. I believe there are not many changes in 3.0.0 (current development branch) so it will be applicable there too with minimal modifications.*

First of all, download Pidgin sources. In Ubuntu this is done simply by running

```
apt-get source pidgin
```

Which will fetch libpurple, pidgin and finch sources. Then go into `pidgin-2.10.9/pidgin/gtkblist.c` and find the line

```c
static GtkItemFactoryEntry blist_menu[] =
```

There you will see Gtk menu in text. Add the following line:

```c
{ N_("/Buddies/Show/_Groups"), NULL, pidgin_blist_show_groups_cb, 1, "<CheckItem>", NULL },
```

after

```c
{ N_("/Buddies/Show/_Empty Groups"), NULL, pidgin_blist_show_empty_groups_cb, 1, "<CheckItem>", NULL },
```

You can see that the line added is just the analog of after which it was added. The 3rd array member is the function responsible for updating menu item status.

Next, add the function you just specified, `pidgin_blist_show_groups_cb`. You can do it finding the `pidgin_blist_show_empty_groups_cb` and copying it's contents.

```c
static void pidgin_blist_show_groups_cb(gpointer data, guint action, GtkWidget *item)
{
    pidgin_set_cursor(gtkblist->window, GDK_WATCH);

    purple_prefs_set_bool(PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_groups",
            gtk_check_menu_item_get_active(GTK_CHECK_MENU_ITEM(item)));

    pidgin_clear_cursor(gtkblist->window);
}
```

Also, you need to set item status on startup. Find the function

```c
static void pidgin_blist_show(PurpleBuddyList *list)
```

and add

```c
gtk_check_menu_item_set_active(GTK_CHECK_MENU_ITEM(gtk_item_factory_get_item (gtkblist->ift, N_("/Buddies/Show/Groups"))),
                                                      purple_prefs_get_bool(PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_groups"));
```

after

```c
gtk_check_menu_item_set_active(GTK_CHECK_MENU_ITEM(gtk_item_factory_get_item (gtkblist->ift, N_("/Buddies/Show/Empty Groups"))),
                                                   purple_prefs_get_bool(PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_empty_groups"));
```

The adding preference `"/blist/show_groups"` as well as adding callback to it is explained in [How do I add custom preference into Pidgin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379642/how-do-i-add-custom-preference-into-pidgin). To test your changes, compile and install pidgin:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep pidgin
cd pidgin-2.10.9/
fakeroot debian/rules binary
sudo dpkg -i ../pidgin_2.10.9-0ubuntu3.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pidgin-3.0.0

There are some changes in the way which Pidgin generates menu in 3.0.0 version. First, there is new array `GtkToggleActionEntry blist_menu_toggle_entries[]`. You need to add there

```c
{ "ShowGroups", NULL, N_("_Groups"), NULL, NULL, G_CALLBACK(pidgin_blist_show_groups_cb), FALSE },
```

after

```c
{ "ShowEmptyGroups", NULL, N_("_Empty Groups"), NULL, NULL, G_CALLBACK(pidgin_blist_show_empty_groups_cb), FALSE },
```

And, there is `static const char *blist_menu`. You need to add

```c
"<menuitem action='ShowGroups'/>"
```

after

```c
"<menuitem action='ShowEmptyGroups'/>"
```

Then follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23379171/2572082) skipping the very first.