# How do I add custom preference into Pidgin?

Tags: c, pidgin

I need to add preference into Pidgin to serve my custom menu item as shown in [How do I add item to Pidgin menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379170/how-do-i-add-item-to-pidgin-menu/23379171#23379171). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find function `pidgin_blist_init` in `pidgin/gtkblist.c` and add the following line:

```c
purple_prefs_add_bool(PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_groups", FALSE);
```

after

```c
purple_prefs_add_bool(PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_empty_groups", FALSE);
```

There are also functions to add `int`, `string`, `none`, `string_list`, `path` and `path_list` types. Now, we need to associate our custom menu item with custom function. This is done in `pidgin_blist_show`. Just add the line

```c
purple_prefs_connect_callback(handle, PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_groups",
                              _prefs_change_redo_list_groups, NULL);
```

after

```c
purple_prefs_connect_callback(handle, PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_empty_groups",
                              _prefs_change_redo_list, NULL);
```

And, finally, add the `_prefs_change_redo_list_groups` function just after the `_prefs_change_redo_list`:

```c
static void _prefs_change_redo_list_groups(const char *name, PurplePrefType type,
                                           gconstpointer val, gpointer data)
{
    purple_blist_set_groups_visible(purple_prefs_get_bool(PIDGIN_PREFS_ROOT "/blist/show_groups"));
    _prefs_change_redo_list(name, type, val, data);
}
```

The `purple_blist_set_groups_visible` will also be published once I develop it, I promise ;)